# Install Ubuntu to another partition from running, installed system on the same disk

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, ubiquity

I have a system where I need to minimize downtime as much as possible. I need to solve upgrades in a way that is as risk free as possible while also keeping downtime very low.

The circumstances are that this is a security system and is gonna be installed and upgraded on many machines that do not belong to us. The machine may be both physical or virtual.

What I wish to achieve:

Install "System One (i.e. Ubuntu 18)" to partition 1.
Boot up the installed "System One"
From within the "System One", **that is running**, install "System Two (i.e. Ubuntu 19)" to partition 2.
Restart and boot up installed "System Two".

This way I will always have first system available if anything goes wrong with newer untested system. Also there are no downtimes during the upgrade of system besides reboot to newer version of the system which is very important.

I've read about installer Ubiquity but found very little explanation of installing system to different disk, much less to just different partition on the same disk.

Is what I wish to achieve even possible? Are there good alternatives that would solve my needs?

Comment: Installing system2 from system 1 after every update doesn't seem like an efficient way to minimize downtime. Why not keep a backup?

Comment: You don't need to re-invent the wheel called "high uptime." Note that very-high-uptime generally requires redundancy and gets expensive. Many shops that require reasonably-high-reliability use two systems: A test system and a production system. You work out the kinks and practice migration on the test system at leisure, and migrate the production system once the process is well-tested. Since your description implies that your budget is low (single machine), look into using VMs or Containers to house your test and production systems.

Comment: @user535733 The circumstances are that this system is gonna be installed and upgraded on many machines that do not belong to us. The machine may be both physical or virtual

Comment: That's important information and should be up in the question above. Look at Ubuntu Core, which is a smaller, snap-only, auto-updating, builtin-failover version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @mikewhatever Considered system is a security system and not easily accessible by me as a machine on which the system is running is not owned by me. The way I mentioned would have downtime only as long as it takes to reboot, which is probably less than a minute, how is that not efficient? Installing new system from scratch is much more failsafe than upgrading existing system, also can you elaborate on backups? Would I be able to easily restore system that I can no longer boot up, and if so, then how?

Comment: @user535733 I didn't mean to pick a fight, just trying to communicate... Back to the topic: I did lookup Ubuntu Core and I am not sure if that would do. As it seems all the packages are read-only and I am not sure about availability of some. Our system is driven by custom service which relies heavily on many other programs and services, and requires to modify configuration files and .service files of many. I have zero experience with Ubuntu Core, but I do have a feeling it would not work for this application.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, FYI I have two computers for that idea, one is 16.04 LTS and another is 18.04 LTS. And each one has a backup file of best point by `fsarchiver`. This alternative also is goof for some physical machine failure, an error can occur to your OS and hardware, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate the original OS, or an OS after updates, without a reboot by use of [dd](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/linux-dd-command-clone-disk-practical-example/) or [GNOME Disk](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-disk-images-using-gnome-disk/). The steps will vary according to the Partition Table Format used ([MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) or [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)).

You will need to disable swap with swapoff before replication, and re-enable it with swapon afterwards. Therefore, a separate swap partition, shared by both instances of the OS, is recommended.

If you do not use an installation app, [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) will not know about the second OS on the second partition. [Amending GRUB manually to permit multibooting](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html) is much more complex than just running through installation again to install another OS instance into partition 2. But, yes, it can be done.

The other alternative is RAID-1, where the second drive continually mirrors the first. If the first instance of the OS fails, the instance on the second drive automatically picks up the slack.

Comment: Sorry, but rebooting is not an option as stated in 'From within the "System One", that is running'. Rebooting should only happen when the new system is prepared.

Comment: Replicating original OS is of no use, as the specific application of this process is to upgrade the system, not create new but same.

Comment: You may also replicate the OS, its configuration, and data after updates using this method.